# Ошибка в glShaderSource

Tags: c#, opengl

Возникает ошибка:

> 1>C:\Users\Виктор\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ShaderProgram\ShaderProgram\Form1.cs(115,48,115,54): error CS1503: Аргумент "3": преобразование типа из "string" в "string[]" невозможно

```
    string[] str = new string[2];
    str[0] = @"

    in  vec3 in_Position;

    void main(void) 
    {
        gl_Position = vec4(in_Position.x, in_Position.y, in_Position.z, 1.0);
    }
    ";

    fragmentSource = @"

    precision highp float; // Драйверы видеокарты требуют это для следующей строки чтобы функционировать должным образом

    out vec4 fragColor;

    void main(void) 
    {
        fragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0); //Устанавливаем цвет каждого фрагмента в белый
    }
    ";        

    /* Назначаем нашим обработчикам "имена" для новых объектов шейдера */
    vertexShader = Gl.glCreateShader(Gl.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fragmentShader = Gl.glCreateShader(Gl.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    IntPtr vIntPtr = Marshal.StringToBSTR(vertexSource);

    /* Объединяем буферы исходных кодов шейдеров с соответствующими обработчиками */
    Gl.glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1,str[0] , IntPtr.Zero);
```

Answer (score 1):

Функция glShaderSource ожидает третьем параметром массив. Попробуйте передать его ей:

Gl.glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, str, IntPtr.Zero);

Но использовать она будет только первый элемент, т.к. 2 параметр функции равен 1.

Comment: Не 3 аргумента а 4.